# Extract arguments

Tags: unix, sed, text-parsing

I am working on automating CUPS (Create user provided services) in Cloud Foundry. I have a `cups.sh` file which contains the corresponding `cf cups` commands to be executed for a particular application. Below is sample:

```
cf cups service-A -p '{"uri": "https://sample uri"}'
cf cups service-B -p '{"uri": "https://sample uri","id": "abcd","token": "xyz"}'
```

I am trying to write a script will perform below use case:

> Parse the cups.sh, line by line and extract the service name (e.g. `service-A`) and the argument following `-p` (e.g: `'{"uri": "https://sample uri","id": "abcd","token": "xyz"}'`).

I am currently using below script:

```
File=cups.sh
sed -e 's/[[:space:]]*#.*// ; /^[[:space:]]*$/d' "$File" | while read line
do
    temp=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f4)
    echo $temp
done
```

This is not accurate as it returns me `"https://sample uri"}'`. Is there a more accurate way of extracting the argument `-p` and using it for further operations?

Comment: It doesn't provide accurate results....I want to store everything after -p argument including brackets and in a variable.

Comment: Assuming your fields are all 'single-space-separated', do `echo $line | cut -d ' ' -f5-`, which prints field 5 and everything else after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract what we need:

```
$> sed -n -r '/^\s*cf\s+cups\s+.+.*-p\s+'"'"'.+'"'"'/{s/\s*cf\s+cups\s+(.+)\s.*-p\s+('"'"'.+'"'"').*$/\1 \2/;p}' cups.sh

service-A '{"uri": "https://sample uri"}'
service-B '{"uri": "https://sample uri","id": "abcd","token": "xyz"}'
```

Now, form commands to push all results into 2 arrays (`_srv` and `_cmd`):

```
$> sed -n -r '/^\s*cf\s+cups\s+.+.*-p\s+'"'"'.+'"'"'/{s/\s*cf\s+cups\s+(.+)\s.*-p\s+('"'"'.+'"'"').*$/_srv+=('"'"'\1'"'"') _cmd+=(\2)/;p}' cups.sh

_srv+=('service-A') _cmd+=('{"uri": "https://sample uri"}')
_srv+=('service-B') _cmd+=('{"uri": "https://sample uri","id": "abcd","token": "xyz"}')
```

Finally, put everything in a bash file

```
#!/bin/bash

_fil=cups.sh
_srv=()
_cmd=()

eval `sed -n -r '/^\s*cf\s+cups\s+.+.*-p\s+'"'"'.+'"'"'/{s/\s*cf\s+cups\s+(.+)\s.*-p\s+('"'"'.+'"'"').*$/_srv+=('"'"'\1'"'"') _cmd+=(\2)/;p}' "$_fil"`

# test

_len=${#_srv[@]}
for (( i=-1;++i<_len; )); do
  echo ${_srv[$i]} ${_cmd[$i]}
done
```

---

1. `^\s*cf\s+cups\s+`: search for lines starting with `cf cups ...`
2. `\s+(.+)\s`: extract the third column (delimited by `\s` (spaces)) as `\1`
3. `-p\s+('"'"'.+'"'"')`: extract the stuff between `''` right after `-p` as `\2` (`''` included)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```sh
$ # only lines with successful substitutions will be printed
$ sed -n 's/.*service-A -p //p' ip.txt
'{"uri": "https://sample uri"}'
$ sed -n 's/.*service-B -p //p' ip.txt
'{"uri": "https://sample uri","id": "abcd","token": "xyz"}'

$ # to save results in variable
$ a=$(sed -n 's/.*service-A -p //p' ip.txt)
$ echo "$a"
'{"uri": "https://sample uri"}'
```

With `awk`

```sh
$ awk -F"'" -v sq="'" '/service-A/{print sq $2 sq}' ip.txt
'{"uri": "https://sample uri"}'
```

To pass search term as variable

```sh
$ st='service-A'
$ sed -n 's/.*'"$st"' -p //p' ip.txt
'{"uri": "https://sample uri"}'

$ awk -F"'" -v s="$st" -v sq="'" '$0 ~ s{print sq $2 sq}' ip.txt
'{"uri": "https://sample uri"}'
```

Comment: can you show how can this be used in the while loop in the question? As i do not want to hard code Service names i.e Service A, Service B etc...